# Using rewrite in the REPL

Tags: idris

For one of the exercises in *Type-Driven Development with Idris*, I wrote the following:

```
myPlusCommutes : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> n + m = m + n
myPlusCommutes Z m = rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral m in Refl
myPlusCommutes (S n) m =
    rewrite myPlusCommutes n m in
      rewrite plusSuccRightSucc m n in Refl
```

Then I wanted to play around with `rewrite` in the REPL, so I could "see" what was happening behind the scenes. I thought the following might work, but it didn't.

```
λΠ> :let m : Nat
defined
λΠ> :let s : (plus 0 m = plus m 0)
defined
λΠ> rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral m in s
rewriting plus m 0 to m did not change type iType
```

**Is it possible to see what `rewrite` is doing using the REPL?**

Comment: Might it be that this is because s is not general enough?
Also, you could as well use `replace`, I might write an answer using this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rewrite x in y` does not change the type of `y` to match the expected type, it change the expected type to match `y`. Idris does not know what the expected type is because you have not provided it.